# VLC Crop Resolution Problems

Tags: video, resolution, vlc-media-player

In order to eliminate black borders when watching movies in VLC player, I usually just crop to 16:9. I am trying to do this on my new laptop (specs below) but when I crop to that resolution, the video freezes while the audio continues. VLC does not freeze, and I am able to continue to cycle through crop resolutions, but video playback will not work on this particular resolution.

- Tried launching VLC app. from integrated GPU, and then dedicated.
- File format does not seem to be an issue, same problem with .mp4/.mkv/etc.
- Doesn't make a difference if I'm viewing on laptop or connecting to TV via HDMI.
- All drivers are updated; I've had this laptop not even a week.
- Didn't have this issue on my last laptop, what's the deal!

Specs:

```
     Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit 
  System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
         System Model: Inspiron 5577
                 BIOS: 1.0.4
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz (8 CPUs), 
            ~2.8GHz
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8054MB RAM
        Dedicated GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
           Hard Drive: 1000 GB Hybrid Drive
                  SSD: 128GB
```

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the problem by switching to OpenGL output in the video settings (normal one, not experimental), instead of automatic output.